# codeigniter php change table orientation to vertical

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can change dthe table orientation from horizontal to vertical?

example

```
$this->table->set_heading('Name', 'Surname');
$tabClient = $this->table->generate($client); 
echo $tabClient;
```

provide

```
Name   Surname
Mark   Mark
Greg   Greg
```

its possible to change to:

```
Name    Mark Greg
Surname Mark Greg
```

Comment: can you provide the structure of your `$client` array?

Comment: i agree to @CodeGodie. Im just trying to guess :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
    //assuming your clients array is in this structure
    $clients = array(
        array("John", "Doe"),
        array("Jane", "Smith"),
    );

    $this->load->library('table');
    $fnames[] = "<strong>Name</strong>";
    $lnames[] = "<strong>Surname</strong>";
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        $fnames[] = $client[0];
        $lnames[] = $client[1];
    }

    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->add_row($fnames);
    $this->table->add_row($lnames);

    $tabClient = $this->table->generate();
    echo $tabClient;
```